# Interactively select which columns are displayed

Tags: r, quarto, reactable

I am using reactable to generate a table in a quarto document. There are a bit too many columns. So I am thinking of displaying a few by default and then allow the user to change that if needed. I am looking for ideas on how to allow the user to have control over which columns are displayed. I am not sure if there is an option in reactable to do this. Alternative ideas and solutions are welcome.

Thoughts:

- [observable](https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/ojs/)?
- Custom JS ([This](https://htmldom.dev/show-or-hide-table-columns/) is a nice implementation.)
- Reformat additional columns and [hide behind an accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dj7Y/2082/)?

```
library(reactable)
reactable(iris)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but it seems to be doable using Observable. Glin shows in [this blogpost](https://glin.quarto.pub/observable-reactable/) how to combine Observable with `reactable` in quarto for filtering rows. For selecting columns something along this lines might work (I am not an ojs user, i.e. I am not really sure how does column selection work here):

````
---
format: html
execute: 
  echo: false
---

## Using Observable Inputs to select variable sin reactable

```{ojs}
//| panel: input

viewof species = Inputs.checkbox(
  ["Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"], 
  { value: ["Species"], label: "Variables:"}
)
```

```{ojs}
//| include: false
data = FileAttachment("iris.csv").csv({ typed: true })

filtered = data[species]

// Update table data when filtered data changes
Reactable.setData('tbl', filtered)
```

```{r}
library(reactable)

data <- read.csv("iris.csv")

reactable(
  data,
  wrap = FALSE,
  resizable = TRUE,
  minRows = 10,
  elementId = "tbl"
)
```
````